# To control decibels in speakers by Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, speakers, modprobe

I need to load the module `pcspkr` to Linux kernel often by `sudo modprobe pcspkr`.
It sometimes happens that something goes totally wrong such that I cannot stand the amount of decibels in my speakers.

I would like to

1. control the amount of decibels in my speakers
2. and to have a visual speaker in my top panel which indicates the amount of decibels in my computer at each given time

How can you solve at least one of the problems?

Comment: Your question is very ambiguous. The `pcspkr` module is only for the
system bell, which is produced by a tiny built-in speaker in the
motherboard. Your real speakers, the ones that make the rest of the
sound, are controlled by other modules. If your linux distro doesn't
detect and load the appropriate modules by default, there's probably
something wrong. So, do you want to control the volume of the system bell or the speakers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `xset` tool to control the volume and pitch of the pc speaker. Quoting from the `xset` man page:

> The b option controls bell volume,
>   pitch and duration.  This option
>   accepts up to three  numerical
>                  parameters, a preceding dash(-), or a ’on/off’ flag.  If no
>   parameters are given, or the ’on’ flag
>                  is used, the system defaults will be used.  If the dash or
>   ’off’  are  given,  the  bell  will 
>   be
>                  turned  off.  If only one numerical parameter is given, the
>   bell volume will be set to that value,
>                  as a percentage of its maximum.  Likewise, the  second 
>   numerical  parameter  specifies  the 
>   bell
>                  pitch,  in  hertz, and the third numerical parameter
>   specifies the duration in
>   milliseconds.  Note
>                  that not all hardware can vary the bell characteristics. 
>   The X server will set  the 
>   characteris‐
>                  tics of the bell as closely as it can to the user’s
>   specifications.

Thus, `xset b 0` should completely mute the speaker and `xset b 100` should set it to its maximum volume.

Answer (score 0):

Normally in Gnome you use the Volume Applet to adjust the volume.  Right-click the top panel and click "Add to Panel...".  Scroll down until you see "Volume Control" and press the Add button.  Now there is a speaker in the top panel that can be used to control the volume and show the current volume.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alsamixer is another way to limit the volume.